# Devolver ciertos campos API NodeJS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api

Tengo un esquema Marca que lo defino de la siguiente manera:

```
let marcaSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: {
        type: String,
        requiredPaths: [true, 'El {PATH} es requerido'],
        unique: true
    },
    estado: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true })
```

Lo que quisiera es que al hacer un GET de todas las marcas, me devuelva unicamente el **_id** y el **nombre** en la respuesta, no el estado y los timestamps. Esto pude resolverlo si devuelvo una unica marca en un GET by ID, pero no se como realizarlo para muchas marcas. Este es el código de mi GET y como lo estoy tratando de resolver. La respuesta es un array vacio ya que no esta iterando entre las marcas para formatear la respuesta pero no se como realizarlo.

```
//============================
// Obtiene todas las marcas
//============================
let getBranch = (req, res) => {
    let pagina = Number(req.query.pagina) || 1;
    let cantidad = Number(req.query.cantidad) || 10;
    Marca.find({ estado: true })
        .skip((pagina * cantidad) - cantidad)
        .limit(cantidad)
        .exec((err, marcas) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    ok: false,
                    error: err
                });
            }
            Marca.countDocuments({ estado: true }, (err, cantidad) => {
                res.json({
                    ok: true,
                    cantidad,
                    marcas: {
                        _id: marcas._id,
                        nombre: marcas.nombre
                    }
                });
            });
        })
};
```

Si elimino esa intento de formateo, y dejo solo marcas en la respuesta, el formato de respuesta es algo asi:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "cantidad": 5,
    "marcas": [
        {
            "estado": true,
            "_id": "5fa006dde8c8633bd00dc9c0",
            "nombre": "Quilmes",
            "createdAt": "2020-11-02T13:17:17.727Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-11-02T13:17:17.727Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        ...
```

En cambio si trato de formatearlo, queda asi:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "cantidad": 5,
    "marcas": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás intentando hacer en el callback de `countDocuments` es incorrecto. [countDocuments](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.countDocuments) es como un análogo a `array.length`. Solamente obtienes el conteo (`cantidad` en tu caso) de elementos disponibles, `marcas` viene del callback de `.exec`.

Por lo que si quieres retornar determinados elementos puedes recurrir a un filter de `marcas`. O más fácil aún sin complicarse la vida. En el método `find` puedes indicar qué elementos quieres retornar separados por espacio. Si miras la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), indica que puedes adicionar una proyección para tal fin.

```javascript
  Marca.find({ estado: true }, '_id nombre')
  /// ...
```